# Настройка htaccess для переадресации

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите в настройке htaccess файла, совсем в этом ничего не понимаю. Необходимо редиректить ссылки типа domain.com/LxTy на адрес domain.com/link.php?address=LxTy. Возможно ли это и если да то как? Признателен за любые ответы.

Comment: Подробнее опишите тип этих ссылок. Каким может быть значение `LxTy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.htacess**

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for projects.php
RewriteRule ^custom$ projects.php [NC,L]

# NC makes the rule non case sensitive
# L makes this the last rule that this specific condition will match
# $ in the regular expression makes the matching stop so that "customblah" will not work

# Rewrite for user.php?u=xxxxx
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

# Rewrite for article.php?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Так теперь по коду : первое RewriteRule ^custom$ projects.php [NC,L] это будет перенаправлять projects.php в адрес типа твойсайт.рф/custom
Второе правило будет перенаправлять твойсайт.рф/user.php?u=Anton в твойсайт.рф/user/Anton или если там цифры твойсайт.рф/user.php?u=38 перенаправит в твойсайт.рф/user/38

и третье правило превратиться в твойсайт.рф/article/1/Hello-World, например.
И вот если знаешь английский посмотри видео - там доходчиво тоже самое https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I

Comment: Спасибо большое за второе правило))